# TextView within TableViewCell resigns first responder

Tags: ios, swift2, uitextview, uitableview

I have a TextView within a TableViewCell. The TextView is delegated to itself and userInteraction is set to false.

When the user taps on the containing cell, the userInteraction for the TextView is enabled and it is set as first responder.

All well so far.

However no sooner has it set the cursor at start ready to type than it decides to resignFirstResponder.

Anything I've forgotten to set or is this looking like a personal issue with some other conflicting code?

Thanks.

Comment: Check if you have the Keyboard section on your table to "Do not dismiss" if you have selected "Dismiss on drag" or "Dismiss interactively" maybe this is your problem, or use this code `self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .None` to make sure that all is ok

Comment: Thx Reinier - Keyboard is set to Do Not Dismiss - I think I've probably got something unique in my code that's causing this but since I've already lost over 6 hours on it I thought best to see if anything obvious missing

Comment: I've noticed that the view is constantly running the tableView.numberOfRowsInSection which suggests it is constantly updating the table. This would seem to be the reason that the responder is resigned as it kills it when it runs a check on the cells. How would I prevent that?

Comment: Add your code to review it, and see what is going on